# Discarding (but not trashing) stories in Pivotal Tracker

Tags: pivotaltracker

I can't figure out how to "discard but keep" a story... I was thinking *reject* was the answer, but I'm not so sure since when I reject it, the story still sits in my current column with a *restart* button visible.

Sometimes I go down the wrong track, create a *Story* (feature) that I realize later I don't need or want. However, I don't want to trash it - I'd like to keep it for future reference, but I want it to go away somewhere - not sit in my current column forever.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Trello has a great "Archive" command if you're looking for an alternative tool that supports this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pivotal Support explains just exactly why nobody posted an answer...

### Short Answer:

*not possible*

### Long Answer (from Pivotal Support):

> Unfortunately there's not a way to archive stories in Tracker and as you've discovered, the reject button doesn't remove stories from
> Current.
>
> In these cases we recommend creating a label describing the situation
> (“on-hold”, “not reproducible”, won't fix", etc.) to apply to such
> stories, and then move the story to the bottom of the Icebox along
> with a concise comment explaining the decision (you must "unstart" the
> story before it can be moved to the Icebox). You can also use a
> release marker in the icebox to separate stories like this from
> others, as in the attached screenshot.​

[image]

Comment: "Ex-Girlfriends Heart" is probably a better name. Its wayyyyy colder than an icebox.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a post by Pivotal themselves that explains what they do with such stories.

https://twitter.com/pivotaltracker/status/337950414244810753

Basically, they mark as `duplicate`, `won't fix`, `won't implement`, etc. After, they set the story points to 0. Then they accept the story so it is still able to be searched on their project. The story points as 0 is important so that accepting the story doesn't increase your velocity for work that essentially wasn't done.

The post is a little old (3 years at time of writing, with 1 year old update), but I haven't found a better way thus far.